# How to choose modified instances in AspectJ?

Tags: class, aop, instance, aspectj

I am studying aspect oriented programming and I want to use AspectJ to create several aspects to change a class. The problem is that all instances of the class are being changed by all aspects, and I want to choose the aspects to use for each instance.

Another problem, how to choose the order of the advices from different aspects for the same method?

Thanks

Comment: You should split this into two questions, since the two things you are asking are unrelated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the answer you are looking for, but it is by design that all instances of a class are modified by an aspect.  You should be thinking that AspectJ affects the semantics of a program as a whole, rather than pieces of it.

AspectJ is implemented through byte code manipulation, so it would not be possible to make the changes for individual instances even that were part of the AspectJ spec.

But, perhaps there is another way of implementing what you need implemented since only requiring weaving into individual instances implies that there is something wrong with your implementation.

Answer (score 2):

I'll only answer partially, for the time being.

Concerning your second question:

> how to choose the order of the advices from different aspects for the
>   same method?

please look at [declare precedence](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/progguide/semantics-declare.html#advice-precedence)